What library does Clonezilla use for TUI?
What library does Clonezilla use to show menus, dialogs, etc in its text user interface? I would like to use it directly as a fail-safe option for GUI apps when no GUI subsystem is available. I presume it is a C library. Does it have python bindings?
I think it would be built on curses, but is there any additional layer on top of that, or is it bare-bones curses? I'd like to be able to create UIs like this:


By default, Clonezilla uses dialog for its TUI, and dialog uses ncurses.
There doesn’t seem to be a document listing Clonezilla’s requirements, but you can see this for example in the main clonezilla script.
Note that Clonezilla can use other dialog-like tools: whiptail (which uses S-Lang to provide a text-mode interface), or in graphical environments, Xdialog, gdialog (for GNOME), or kdialog (for KDE).
